# How to write function with variable from the outside?

Tags: python, function, scope, definition

I hope you can help. I am looking for a way to write a function that inserts one item later. Let me show you an example:

```
def general_poly(L):
        """ 
        L, a list of numbers (n0, n1, n2, ... nk)
        Returns a function, which when applied to a value x, returns the value 
        n0 * x^k + n1 * x^(k-1) + ... nk * x^0 
        """
        x = 1
        res = 0
        n = len(L)-1
        for e in range(len(L)):
            res += L[e]*x**n
            n -= 1
        return res
```

I thought I could just give `x` a value here and once I do `general_poly(L)(10)` it will be replaced so that `x = 10` but apparently it is not that easy. What do I have to change / add so that my function works? How does the function know, that the multiplication is the `x`? Thanks for your help, guys!

Comment: If `x` is global, you need to explicitly tell Python that via `global x`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are being asked to return a function but you are returning the calculated value:

```
def general_poly(L):
    """ 
    L, a list of numbers (n0, n1, n2, ... nk)
    Returns a function, which when applied to a value x, returns the value 
    n0 * x^k + n1 * x^(k-1) + ... nk * x^0 
    """
    def inner(x):
        res = 0
        n = len(L)-1
        for e in range(len(L)):
            res += L[e]*x**n
            n -= 1
        return res
    return inner
```

Now `general_poly(L)(10)` will do what you expect but it is probably more useful if you assign it to a value, so it can be called it multiple times, e.g.:

```
L = [...]
fn = general_poly(L)
print(fn(10))
print(fn(3))
```

You could also rewrite `inner` to:

```
def general_poly(L):
    return lambda x: sum(e*x**n for n, e in enumerate(reversed(L)))
```

Comment: It does indeed what I want, thanks. But I am still confused: The return of `inner` basically returns the setup so that once `x` is given the inner function can be solved. Is that correct? If so, how does general_poly(L) know that the `x` is coming after the def of general_poly? Because inner is def as inner(x)?

Comment: Yes, `general_poly` is a function of one param (L) that is returning a function that takes one parameter (x). Obviously the actual names of the parameters are immaterial.

Comment: The fact `L` is still accessible to `inner()` is called a closure.

Comment: Why would you want to rewrite ```inner``` as a lambda function??

Comment: Because the function is now just a one-liner and the fact there is no real value in giving the function a name, given you are just returning it. It's a matter of style, and I'm okay with others having a different opinion.

Answer (score 0):

```
def general_poly (L):
    """ L, a list of numbers (n0, n1, n2, ... nk)
    Returns a function, which when applied to a value x, returns the value 
    n0 * x^k + n1 * x^(k-1) + ... nk * x^0 """

    def inner(x):
        L.reverse()
        return sum(e*x**L.index(e) for e in L)
    return inner
```