# Python 3: Use n*x**k to evaluate a list (general_poly)

Tags: python

[I am trying to answer the same exam question as this OP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40315105/how-to-write-function-with-variable-from-the-outside) and, although the posts are related the help requested is different.

I'll talk about my test cases and why I'm thinking it has to be a semantic error in a moment but first...

The exam problem:

> Write a function called general_poly, that would, for example, evaluate >*general_poly([1, 2, 3, 4])(10)* to *1234* because 
>   *1*10^3 + 2*10^2 + 3*10^1 + >4*10^0*.
>
> So in the example the function only takes one argument with
>   general_poly([1, 2, 3, 4]) and it returns a function that you can
>   apply to a value, in this case x = 10 with general_poly([1, 2, 3,
>   4])(10).

My code:

```
def general_poly(L):
    def in_poly(x):
        total = 0
        for i in range(0, len(L)):
            k = (len(L)-1) - i 
            total += (L[i] * (x**k))
        return total
    return in_poly(x)
```

We are not told what the error(s) are specifically or given the lists used to test the code, only a pass/fail (*error thrown*), and the correct answer for each of the six tests.

However, we are given a hint because the answer to the first question is 1234, which is the example that was given.

I know I should get *that* one right at least, but the code is failing all six tests.

These are some of the test cases that I have run -  and verified the results with a calculator - so I don't think the calculations wrong:
general_poly:

- ([1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4])(10) = 12341234;
- ([1,2,3,4])(0) = 4;
- ([1,2,3,4])(-7) = -262;
- ([5,6,7,8,9])(28) = 3210713;
- ([103, 42, -78, -3.26])(9) = 77783.74

I have also checked the indentation, checked that there was output, run through it line by line, checked spelling, etc. but no luck.

It may be connected to the fact that I can't call the function as general_poly(L)*(x)*. I have to declare x separately before I call the function or I get:

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

Comment: @Morgan Thrapp I just tried to edit my code formatting error but you beat me to it. Thank you.

Comment: No problem. There has to be a blank line before formatted code in markdown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Return the function without calling it

```
return in_poly
```

not

```
return in_poly(x)
```

`in_poly(x)` is an integer, not a function.

Comment: Which, for the record, is exactly what the traceback says in `TypeError: 'int' object is not callable`.

Comment: @Patrick I had tried that and it didn't work... when you stopped through on  python tutor cause it wouldn't implement the function. However, that change was it 20/20!  Thank all!

Comment: @Andre that was the reason I didn't try it in the grader where I was down to 4 chances to get the right answer. So Anaconda raises an error but the grader didn't. Perhaps it's because it was being returned to another function in the grader, but not in mine.