# Python: define function only once

Tags: python

I want to define a function, e.g. a polynomial, from a list of prefactors. Something like

```
order = [1,0,1]

def poly(x):
    res = 0
    for i, o in enumerate(order):
      res += o * x**i
    return res
```

so `poly(x)` returns `1 + x²`.

I need to call that function multiple times for different `x`, but with the same prefactors. The above function executes the for loop every time it is called, which is rather inefficient, especially if the `order` list is long.
How can I loop only once and call the result for different `x`? What is the pythonic solution?

Comment: You have the most efficient solution that I can think of at this time

Comment: I would avoid raising to the power at each iteration by keeping the previous value and just multiplying it by `x` each iteration. This will also eliminate the need in `enumerate` and `i`.

Comment: See if https://stackoverflow.com/questions/533382/dynamic-runtime-method-creation-code-generation-in-python helps.

Comment: *How can I loop only once and call the result for different x? What is the pythonic solution?* - there is no even *mathematical* solution for this. Perhaps you can "hide" the loop, but not to avoid it.

Comment: NumPy also has a method that handles evaluating polynomials: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/generated/numpy.polynomial.polynomial.polyval.html#numpy.polynomial.polynomial.polyval

Comment: Thanks AChampion, I didn't find https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40315105/how-to-write-function-with-variable-from-the-outside
the answers provided there brought me to the solution:
define poly as a function of order, call the function with the wanted order list and write this into a variable. this variable can now be called with different x.

But as Eugene point out already, this actually only hides the for loop, still the execution is reasonably faster!

Thanks for the fast help!

Comment: The method @EugeneSh. is referring to is known as [Horner's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method).

Comment: This was an interesting question, I've never tried to do code generation in Python before. There were some wrinkles I had to work through.

Answer (score 1):

**Code #1:** sum for loop (slow)

```
def poly(x,order=[1,0,1]) : return sum([o*x**i for i,o in enumerate(order)])
```

**Example:**

`poly(2,order=[2,0,2])`

```
>> 10
>> Execution time: 5.29289245605e-05
```

**Code #2:** Sum map (faster)

```
def poly(x,order=[1,0,1]) : return sum(map(lambda (i,o): o*x**i,enumerate(order)))
```

**Example:**

`poly(2,order=[2,0,2])`

```
>> 10
>> Execution time: 3.00407409668e-05
```

Comment: How is it answering the question?

Comment: @EugeneSh. How is it not?

Comment: The question is *How can I loop only once and call the result for different x?*

Comment: As far as I am aware you can't avoid the loop, I have obfuscated by using a map, so I answered the second part `What is the pythonic solution?`

Comment: So the first part of your comment is pretty much the answer to the question. Everything else is just side notes.

Comment: The last line of OP's query was a question.

Answer (score 1):

Python cannot outwit mathematics. The only optimization that comes to mind is avoiding the calculation of terms you multiply by zero anyway:

```
def poly(x, order=(1, 0, 1)):
    res = 0
    for i, o in enumerate(order):
        if o:
            res += o * x**i
    return res
```

As one-liner:

```
def poly2(x, order=(1, 0, 1)):
    return sum(o * x**i for i, o in enumerate(order) if o)
```

Answer (score 1):

Taking the suggestion of @Eugene Sh the repeated raising of powers can be eliminated:

```
xx = 1

def poly(x, order):
    global xx
    xx = 1
    def f(x, o):
        global xx
        ret = xx * o
        xx *= x
        return ret
    return sum(f(x,o) for o in order)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def make_poly(order):
    expression = ''
    for i, o in enumerate(order):
        if o:
            if expression:
                expression += ' + '
            multiplier = '%d * ' % o if o > 1 else ''
            if i == 0:
                expression += str(o)
            elif i == 1:
                expression += multiplier + 'x'
            else:
                expression += multiplier + 'x**%d' % i
    loc = {}
    exec('def f(x):\n    return ' + expression, {}, loc)
    return loc['f']
```

This creates an expression from the passed list, removing all terms that are zero and other redundant operations. Then `exec` is used to create a function which is returned.

```
>>> poly = make_poly([1, 0, 1])
>>> poly(5)
26
```